# what is exact difference between configuring a software and integration in OIM

Tags: oauth, admin, oim

I am new to OIM so while installing and doing real-time scenario  I always saw these terms configuration and integration. I want to know the exact difference please let me clarify all these related to OIM and as well as OAM terms.

Answer (score 1):

In order to know the difference between Configuration and Integration, here are few examples with reference to OAM and OIM. 
The term integration as in "[integration of OIM with OAM](https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/idm/suite/12.2.1.3/idmrn/whats-new-identity-management-12c-release-2-12.2.1.3.0.html#GUID-513BD1A1-48BF-44EA-8496-D5C52D04F519)", and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E52734_01/oim/IDMIG/oim.htm#IDMIG4000), for example, would mean how OIM software connects with OAM, or the plumbing between OIM and OAM. The primary function of OIM is to provide Identity governance and life cycle management of users. And primary function of OAM is to provide access management for users accessing applications in your environment. Now if OAM and OIM are integrated together (following the steps of integration between these OAM and OIM as published/supported by Oracle), then in your environment you achieve user access management to applications along with their life cycle management capabilities - i.e if a user is deprovisioned from OIM, this user is automatically unable to access any of the applications now, because now OAM and OIM are integrated together. 
Compare this to the scenario if these two products were not integrated together, i.e. used as standalone, meaning there is no plumbing or connection between OAM and OIM - as you can see both the functions of user life cycle management and access management are now handled in silos or independent of each other. With Oracle Identity Management suite you get the power of integration with several supported products. e.g. with integration between OAM, OIM and OID, all three products are integrated together to provide a cohesive and a powerful Identity Management solution in your environment.

Now about the second term "configuration". Configuration means to configure settings, for example, when you are installing OIM or you could  be configuring various ini files, timeout settings, various parameters, etc. Also one would also be configuring various settings/parameters during integration steps as well, for example during the OAM and OIM integration.

Some examples of configuration - 
"[Configuring the Server-Side session lifecyle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E52734_01/oam/AIAAG/GUID-EC25976D-C535-4DE1-9D68-21B7406B17EF.htm#AIAAG35379)".

"[Preparing to Install and Configure Oracle Identity and Access Management"](https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/idm/suite/12.2.1.3/inoam/preparing-install-and-configure-product.html#GUID-16F78BFD-4095-45EE-9C3B-DB49AD5CBAAD)